# How can I derive this thermodynamically equivalent expression for the speed of sound?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, acoustics

**Background**

In *Viscous Fluid Flow* by White, the speed of sound for a gas is given as
$$\tag{1-71}
a^2 = \frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\big|_s
$$
where the partial derivative is computed at constant entropy.

White mentions that a thermodynamically equivalent expression is
$$\tag{1-72}
a^2 =\gamma \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_T
$$
where the partial derivative is evaluated at constant temperature and $\gamma$
is the ratio of specific heats (not necessarily constant)
$$
\gamma = \frac{c_p}{c_v}=\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\big|_p/\frac{\partial e}{\partial T}\big|_v
$$

White writes

> The student may prove as an exercise that  Eqs. (1-71) and (1-72) are thermodynamically identical.

White provides this relationship *before* defining an ideal gas or the ideal gas law. Therefore, it's reasonable to assume that this expression can be derived strictly from thermodynamic principles without using the ideal gas assumption.

**Question**

Assuming an adiabatic, reversible (isentropic) process, how do I show that $\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\big|_s$ is equivalent to $\gamma \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_T$?

---

*Notes*

As I have been trying to derive this expression, I found a few expressions which might be useful:

If $p=p(\rho,s)$,
$$
dp = \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_s d\rho + \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\right)_\rho ds
$$
since $ds=0$,
$$
\frac{dp}{d\rho}=\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_s
$$
If $p=p(\rho,T)$,
$$
dp = \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_T d\rho + \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_\rho dT
$$
so
$$
\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_s = \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_T + \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_\rho \frac{dT}{d\rho}
$$
That at least gives some kind of relationship between $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_s$ and $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\right)_T$.

Another relationship which may be useful is
$$
\frac{dp}{d\rho}=\frac{p}{\rho}\frac{d h}{d e}
$$
which can be derived from the 1st Law of Thermodynamics and the definition of enthalpy. The reason I think this is useful is because, if we *could* assume an ideal gas, then $p/\rho=\frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}\big|_T =RT$ and $\frac{dh}{de}$ I think can be manipulated to $c_p/c_v$ somehow.

Comment: For an ideal gas, $R=(c_p-c_v)$

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea by expanding a differential term with different parameters held constant. You can find more guidance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities#Derivation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the density definition $\rho\equiv m/V$, a constant-mass assumption, and the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule):

\begin{align}\frac{\left.\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right|_S}{\left.\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}\right|_T}=\frac{\left.\dfrac{\partial P}{(-m/V^2)\partial V}\right|_S}{\left.\dfrac{\partial P}{(-m/V^2)\partial V}\right|_T}=\frac{\left.\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right|_S}{\left.\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial V}\right|_T}=\frac{-\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial S}\right)^{-1}_P\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial P}\right)^{-1}_V}{-\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)^{-1}_P\left(\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial P}\right)^{-1}_V}=\frac{\left.\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_P}{\left.\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right|_V}=\frac{c_P}{c_V}\equiv\gamma.\end{align}